# What benefit would God gain from multiple religions worshiping him?

Tags: religion, gods

Our religion speaks of the creator of the universe, Krishna, descending upon the world in a time of great crisis. This being would be spiritually pure and wipe all evil from the world, ushering in an age of peace.

Krishna would take the form of an avatar, the manifestation of god made flesh. This human incarnation would rule the planet as a living deity, leading the human race into the golden age of humanity. However, the prophecy surrounding God was not entirely correct. Krishna arrived as the myths states, but he appeared as seven avatars instead of one. These partial avatars, known as "arishnas" represent Krishna in different forms, but share the same underlying consciousness.

These arishnas each placed their roots down in the different continents: North and South America, Eurasia, Antarctica, Australia. There, they set up their own religions and priesthoods, with the people of that continent worshipping them as its leader. Our unified world religion became seven different faiths, each worshipping a different living arishna instead of the one god.

As avatars are worshipped, the original being of Krishna gains power from all avatars being prayed to. In a fictionalized version of our world, there are three religions that worship the same god, but in different ways. They are known as Judaism, Christianity, and Islam, with them being 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0 respectively. This is because they were formed in different time periods by different people, which explains the vast differences between them. As there are no living manifestations of God, everyone is worshipping it based on their own subjective experience. In the real world however, there are living deities walking the earth who are in direct contact with people.

What would God benefit from having multiple religions based on him rather than establishing one unifying creed?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does God need a benefit from having worshippers? Does it have a purpose? If for example it's only a way to distinguish between God's worshippers or not a worshipper, it wouldn't matter what version they worship right?

Comment: Strength of numbers. For whatever reason God needs religion, how will that not be multiplied by "extra" religions? In any case, how is that not a real-world Question of religion or philosophy?

Comment: I feel like this is conceptually related to American Gods. Some gods feed on prayers, others on blood.

Comment: A true God (omnipotent being that created the world) doesn't benefit from anything at the worshipers' level of understanding. Rather, she imparts a reality onto a world for reasons that must be beyond their comprehension. So the real question is, "what benefit do worshipers gain from multiple religions?", or "what is God's purpose in allowing worshipers to fracture their belief in her across multiple religions?". Towards these questions, I like @Jedediah's answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Everyone needs a balanced diet.

Comment: Why? For fun, of course.. God can have fun, can't He?

Comment: *"What would God benefit from having multiple religions based on him rather than one unifying creed?"*  If you explain to us why God benefits from one religion then we can explain why he benefits from more than one. Please can you make it clear what sort of benefits this god is interested in. Otherwise there is no criterion to judge by.

Comment: In the Black & White games, you (the god) gained power (ability to physically affect the world) from having more followers. If you end up with no followers then you lose.

Comment: Don't put the blame on the worshippers. I am certain that God is suffering from multiple personality disorder.

Answer (score 17):

God feeds of the souls of zealots dying a violent death and of human suffering in general. Fomenting religious wars and genocides is supplying him with loads of delicious astral nourishment.

Answer (score 12):

## Eggs in different baskets

If you have a very homogeneous set of believers, all it takes is one fundamental change in belief, one genocide or one pandemic which they won't fight against to wipe out your entire belief base.

Some variety gives you more chances to survive whatever. It's just like genetic variance in a population. Too much of the same makes your base stale.

Comment: I would also add to this "people are different and what is meaningful to them is different; more variety can appeal to more people".  Also different cultures finds different things important.

Answer (score 5):

### Scenario 1:God is meeting the people halfway, and different nations are in different places in their progress towards the necessary virtues

Why should Krishna assume that each nation is going to be equally prepared for the golden age?  Those in America may tend to be better at tolerance of difference, but bad at conforming to those few inflexible expectations required to build a true golden age.  On the other hand, those on the other side of the world may be better at accepting social conformity when it matters, but they need to be helped along to greater flexibility and independence.

Because Krishna is able to split himself so easily, he meets different regions where they are, with a different avatar and slightly different religious tenets depending on what each society most needs.

Later, when all people have been prepared to join into one great utopia, the arishnas can likewise meld back into one great God.

### Scenario 2: The different faiths are set up for different kinds of people

Your neighbor is an introvert; you're an extrovert.  Your brother is a conservative; you're a liberal.  You all can get along (sometimes, if you're all trying to), but at a fundamental level, you may never *want* to live the same life, the same way, or even in the same sort of society.

Each arishna appeals to a different basic personality profile, and after the initial establishment of the religions, different people are eventually able to join up to whichever option best suits them.  None of the "competing" religions are "wrong", or condemned by members of the other religions (this is, after all, a golden age!).  But if you're tired of that Antarctic arishna's chilly, self-sufficient philosophy, and feel a need to change your life to something more warm and communal, there's a temple to the Eurasian arishna just down the street, and you can start attended there, and make new friends and find a new way of life - without ever having abandoned the truth!

And throughout the golden age, the different faiths live in harmony with each other, while each is free to celebrate and enjoy their uniqueness, and the light of their own adopted arishna.

Comment: You must be writing as an American, based on "Those in America may tend to be better at tolerance of difference"

Answer (score 4):

If we made being worshipped the equivalent of getting a salary, being worshipped under multiple aliases is like getting multiple salaries under different names while falling in a lower tax bracket.

So, instead of being taxed at 40% for 100000 wanlon gross "income" under the name U.R.G., there will be let's say 10 aliases, each receiving 10000 wanlon gross "income" and being taxed at 25%.

U.R.G would get a net of 60000 wanlon, while the 10 aliases would get a net of 10 x 7500 = 75000 wanlon.

Plus different religions would take care of the overpopulation by themselves with the frequent religion wars, leaving the god some free time.

Answer (score 1):

### **Mortal's belief mold the deity**

Krishna is polyfacetic. The reason they descended as different avatars is because each represent a different part of them. But religions praise one aspect of the divinity above all others. Even if the scriptures say the god has many sides, their following still picks one and holds it above all others.

If nothing is done to alleviate this, then the god becomes what is believed of them. If their only cult is hinged on compassion and gentleness, they forget their fury. If they are praised for their vengeful nature, they become incapable of forgiveness. So they take many forms, each with a prominent trait that is simple to see, and thus the praise and beliefs they receive molds them to hold all of those traits as important, instead of holding one above all others.

This can have implications, since they can choose to "hide" a side of themselves and in centuries that side will have dissapeared, and the politics and wars of mortals can and do transform them into something different from what they wanted to become.